# How to see IPs of user using the most SYN_RECV, TIME_WAIT, etc?

Tags: tcp, netstat

Does anyone recommend (or have a netstat script) that will print the IP sending the most of X (where X is FIN_WAIT, SYN_RECV, etc.).

Like, I have this

`netstat -nat | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n`

Which will nicely print out:

```
  1 CLOSE_WAIT
  1 established)
  1 Foreign
  3 FIN_WAIT1
  3 LAST_ACK
 13 ESTABLISHED
 17 LISTEN
154 FIN_WAIT2
327 TIME_WAIT
```

But I don't know how to figure out which IP is sending the most `TIME_WAIT`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netstat -nat | awk '/TIME_WAIT/ { sub(/:[0-9]+/, "", $5); print $5 }' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head`

Comment: incredible!! :)